# ArrayList-Modificar elementos y buscar

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, qt-creator

Tengo un problema con un `arrayList`. Quiero buscar un producto de tienda. Al crear un método buscar, este lo busca, pero imprime los datos del último producto ingresado. Lo único que imprime bien es el nombre, pero la unidad y el precio imprime del último producto ingresado.

No sé cuál es el error. Este es mi código del método buscar:

```
public void buscar() {

    print("buscas: ");
    nombre=leer.next();
    for(producto buscar: productos) {
        if(nombre.equals(buscar.getNombre())) {
            }else if(nombre.equals(buscar.getNombre())) {
            print("no se ha encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```

También tengo otro inconveniente.

Quiero modificar mi producto, cambiar el nombre, precio y unidad.

A continuación dejo el otro código para modificar los productos.

```
public void modificarTienda() {

    print("Producto a cambiar: ");
    nombre=sc.next();
            
    for(producto buscar: productos) {
        if(nombre.equals(buscar.getNombre())) {
            print ("unidad: "); 
            unidad=sc.nextInt();
            print("Precio: "); 
            precio=sc.nextDouble();
            //productos= new producto(nombre, precio, unidad);
        }
        else {
            print("producto no encontrado");
        }
    }
```

Comment: primero nunca jamas se usa un print en un metodo. El metodo va a una clase y luego en el main lo llamas y ya le pones lo print que quieras.Segundo de que esta compuesto el List donde lo creas?que contiene cada objeto?para modficar algo deberas usar los get y los set del objeto

Answer (score 1):

creo que tu problema es de orden ya que haces print en métodos donde no se puede. Aquí te adjunto la solución con una clase Gestora

Clase Producto:

```
    public class Producto {
        private String nombre;
        private int unidad;
        private double precio;
    
        public Producto(String nombre, int unidad, double precio) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.unidad = unidad;
            this.precio = precio;
        }
    
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    
        public int getUnidad() {
            return unidad;
        }
    
        public void setUnidad(int unidad) {
            this.unidad = unidad;
        }
    
        public double getPrecio() {
            return precio;
        }
    
        public void setPrecio(double precio) {
            this.precio = precio;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Producto{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", unidad=" + unidad + ", precio=" + precio + '}';
        }
```

Clase Gestora

```
public class GestorProductos {
    
    private static ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos;
    
    public static void inicializar() {
        listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public static boolean addProducto(Producto p) {
        return listaProductos.add(p);
    }
    
    public static Producto buscar(String nombre) {
        for (Producto p : listaProductos) {
            if(nombre.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public static Producto modificarTienda(String nombre, int unidad, double precio) {
        for (Producto p : listaProductos) {
            if(nombre.equals(p.getNombre())) {
                p.setNombre(nombre);
                p.setUnidad(unidad);
                p.setPrecio(precio);
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Clase Main

```
public class Tienda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GestorProductos.inicializar();
        
        Producto p1 = new Producto("pan", 3, 0.23);
        GestorProductos.addProducto(p1);
        Producto p2 = new Producto("huevos", 4, 2.45);
        GestorProductos.addProducto(p2);
        Producto p3 = new Producto("harina", 5, 5.67);
        GestorProductos.addProducto(p3);
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del artículo");
        String nombre = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de unidades del artículo");
        int unidad = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introdizca el precio");
        double precio = teclado.nextDouble();
        Producto encontrado = GestorProductos.buscar(nombre);
        if(encontrado == null) {
            System.out.println("No hay ningún artículo con ese nombre");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(encontrado);
        }
        Producto modificado = GestorProductos.modificarTienda(nombre, unidad, precio);
        if(modificado == null) {
            System.out.println("No hay ningún artículo con ese nombre");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(modificado);
        }
    }
    
}
```